# What would body armour designed for women look like?

Tags: near-future, armors

Currently pretty much all body armour is designed for men, then sometimes adapted for women (although very often it isn't). So what would body armour designed for the use of women look like? (Technology is near future)

Comment: The problem has already been identified and is being addressed in the real world. For example, "[Female Soldiers Are Getting New Body Armor Designed Just For Them](https://www.npr.org/2021/07/19/1017774038/female-soldiers-are-excited-about-new-body-armor-that-is-designed-for-them?t=1639118799157)" (22-Jul-2021) by Jay Price, on the (American) National Public Radio web site. Apparently, the (American) Army's Program Executive Office Soldier is doing the necessay adjustments, which, as far as I can tell, basically consist in providing smaller sizes.

Comment: I think in the army there is no distinction between men and women, colors, races, etc which is why the uniform often looks alike. Maybe to entice more women into the force, we can put more effort into the design but otherwise I don't see any good reason. Even the female bodyguards wear suits and ties so why the need to diversify?

Comment: Same as those made for males. Primary objective of armor is to protect vital organs. Both sexes have those roughly in same places. All you do adjust dimensions to fit body types. Adjustable straps, maybe? As scifi: some self-molding to enable mass production.

Comment: @AlexP - thanks for linking an interesting article, but read through it again.  It describes a woman no longer needing to push (something...) aside to "seat" a weapon.  I don't know anything about this field, and the differences in design may be subtle, but the subtle difference between shooting first and shooting second seems pretty important.  A good answer to this question may be technical, but it should not be dismissed.

Comment: according to RPG's, like a bikini.

Comment: @MikeSerfas: The point of the comment and the link is that: (1) the necessity of adjusting the design of body armor for female soldiers has been recognized in the real world; (2) the relevant design groups of the U.S. Army (and, most likely, other armies) are actively developing female specific designs; and thus (3) the question cannot start from scratch, it must recognize that the problem is being addressed in the real world and must indicate what research was done before asking the question, and why the results of the research are unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 5):

it won't look any different. men and woman have the same vital organs.

of the shelf armour would just be non gendered. or the same and just marketed differently.

fitted armour would just be that. custom made and fitted to the person it is for. if it primary purpose is protection then you won't see a difference from the outside.